# how to register YUI drag event

Tags: javascript, yui, jsplumb

I've read http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/dd/, but still have no clue how to register a drag event.

I'm using jsPlumb.draggable to make all the .w class divs draggable, and I wanted to call a hander when the element gets dragged.

Is the following coding valid?

```
                jsPlumb.draggable(Y.all(".w"));

            Y.all(".w").on('drag:drag', function() { alert('Do Something Here'); });
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can listen to the drag event using jsPlumb.

YUI has a `Drag` class which is the one that fires the `drag` event. Usually you'd create an instance of this class and that would be enough to make your node draggable.

```
var dd = new Y.DD.Drag({
  node: '#foo'
});
dd.on('drag:drag', function () {
  // do something
});
```

But jsPlumb creates a hidden `Drag` instance and keeps it to itself. There doesn't seem to be a way to retrieve that `Drag` instance. My recommendation would be to open an issue in jsPlumb's GitHub asking for a way to do this.